# Angular 6 CoreUI and datepicker

Tags: angular-material, angular6, core-ui

I use [CoreUI](https://coreui.io) (angular 6 version) in order to create a simple panel.

I need to have a datepicker, but cannot manage to find how to do it.
Angular material might be a nice solution, but I don manage to include it - looks like there are some basic conflicts.

Any simple solution?

Answer (score 1):

you install a date-time-picker package:

npm install --save angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker bootstrap moment open-iconic

```js
// added the following to app.module.ts

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { DlDateTimePickerDateModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    DlDateTimePickerDateModule,
  ],
  providers: [FormsModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

//added the following to  app.component.html

<dl-date-time-picker
 startView="day"
 maxView="year"
 minView="minute"
 minuteStep="5"
 [(ngModel)]="selectedDate"
>
</dl-date-time-picker>

// added following to ./src/styles.css

@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
@import '~open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add **`ngx-bootstrap`**, it has BootStrap datepicker compatible with Bootstrap V3 & V4.
You can check it here: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker

To **install** ngx-bootstrap, run this command

```
ng add ngx-bootstrap  --component datepicker
```

Then add the following code to your **AppModule**

```
import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';


@NgModule({
  imports: [BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),...]
})
export class AppModule(){}
```

Sample usage (at the **template**):

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Datepicker" class="form-control" bsDatepicker>
```